# Can anyone manipulate the iPad keyboard

Tags: ipad, keyboard

I am looking for some info surrounding the iPad keyboard. WITHOUT jailbreaking the device, I was curious if someone has been been able to manipulate the look of the keyboard. The functionality should remain the same, but the actual look should change. I was curious if anyone could change the color or shape of the keys.

Comment: The whole point of jail breaking is to get access to the root file system, in order to make manipulations like the ones you ask about... It's like "How can I walk into my house without unlocking the doors/windows?"

Comment: There is no way to alter the iOS keyboard without jailbreaking. Not even legitimate apps can touch the keyboard. The only option is to use the different keyboards available (black translucent or default) in iOS. Apple has restricted alteration of the keyboard to sustain a high level of usability.

Answer (score 2):

Not without jailbreaking. With a jailbreak, there are several options for doing this though.

The one that comes to mind immediately is [Winterboard](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/winterboard), which isn't relegated just to keyboards, but theming the entire OS.

There is also [Color Keyboard](http://cydia.saurik.com/package/net.9eye.colorkeyboard), which changes the look and feel of the iOS keyboard (although it is iPhone only).

Comment: Does the possibility exist to create an app that could then skin the keyboard, or does Apple make that totally off limits? Similar to the app "Pimp Your Screen" which allows you to download content from the appstore and skin your app icons and wallpaper layout.

Comment: Per the UI guidelines, you must use one of several specific keyboards: Default, ASCII Capable, URL, Number Pad, Phone Pad, Name Phone Pad, E-mail Address, Decimal Pad, and the Twitter-specific keyboard. Each of them has their own layout, and color scheme, which must remain consistent. There are other keyboard replacement apps, but they do not interact with other apps to specifically override the Apple keyboards.

Comment: Can you enhance your answer and indicate which specific options there are in jailbreak land? Adding links and short description will make the answer much more valuable.

Comment: @patrix, sure, I can... but since the OP didn't want to jailbreak, I figured it would be off-topic. :-)

Comment: @Dave The point of Stack Exchange is not to just help a single person; our long-term goal is to build a resource of good answers that help many people.

Comment: @Doorknob, I couldn't agree more. I intend to do that. Yet, depending upon the whim of the readership, things can get modded down. (i.e., -1 because the OP specifically said they didn't want jailbreak apps, etc.) This is probably a meta topic, so I'll stop here, but you can see how that would get confusing and even frustrating.

Comment: WinterBoard cannot modify the keyboard, just FYI. It can only handle PNGs and string files. The iOS keyboard is mostly code-based and that's why people had to write an app that hooks into mobile substrate.

Comment: @cksum, good point. There is a difference between theming, and wholesale changes to the KB.

Comment: Hey guys, so an example of what im looking for is miTypwriter. This app is its own app for writing notes or stories and has its own skinned keyboard that looks like an old typewriter. My question is, can i get that skin to show up when i write texts or email or enter
stuff online? Secondly, since it does seem like there are preset UI keyboards, is there a way to create an option within settings to allow myself to tell the ipad what keyboard to use where, OR to change the default look of the keyboard all together.

Comment: Not really, ColorKeyboard does theme the keyboard. The difference is in how the programs work. WB just doesn't hook into iOS deep enough to alter such things. I am a developer of iOS JB themes (have one in the Cydia Store), so this is an area I am more than familiar with. You may want to remove mention of WB from your answer as it has no bearing on keyboards.